# How to draw arrow lines on Map v2 in android

Tags: android-maps-v2

How to draw poly line with arrow head(It indicates the direction) using Android Maps V2 API. In Android Maps Documentation this option is not available.Is it possible to add arrows on polyline?

Answer (score 3):

Your best option would be to add a custom `Marker` to the map and position it at the same position as the line's end (or start) point. You will need to make it flat and set its rotation manually.

Fortunately, Google Maps Utils can help out with computing the heading (rotation).

Just add `compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3.4'` as a dependency in your `build.gradle` file

The library has a class called `com.google.maps.android.SphericalUtil` and has amongst other utils the static method

```
public static void double computeHeading(LatLng from, LatLng to)
```

Set the value (which is in degrees) as the markers rotation.

The arrowhead could be a simple bitmap, or even better a drawable Shape.

Comment: Can you give me complete implementation of this code